# Better Way to programmatically detect a key press?

Tags: c++, windows, keypress

I'm currently using this:

```
while (1)
    {
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_F1))
        {
        //do something
        }
    }
```

to detect if a user presses a certain key, in this case F1. I've found that this eats up cpu usage by quite a bit, my question is, is there a better way to detect key presses?

Comment: Window messages if possible. Probably a hook if not.

Comment: Put a short sleep within the while loop. You don't need to check the key 100 million times per second, just about 50. On UNIX, you can look at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/usleep.html

Comment: So i'd just be: `while (1)
    { sleep(50);
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_F1))
        {
        //do something
        }
    }`?

Comment: Using `Sleep` is ill-advised as you will inevitably lose key presses. This is what messages are for. Write a proper window proc that processes messages, and do a standard message pump.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The better way of doing this is using your `WndProc()`. So use standard `WM_KEYDOWN`/`WM_KEYUP` messages to handle keyboard input. Here is an example:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc( HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam )
{
  switch ( uMsg )
  {
    case WM_CLOSE:
        DestroyWindow(hwnd);
    break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
    break;
      case WM_KEYDOWN:
      if ( wParam == VK_F1 )
      {
        // Do something here
        return 0L;
      }
      break;
  }

  return DefWindowProc( hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam );
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wc;
    HWND hwnd;
    MSG Msg;

    //Step 1: Registering the Window Class
    wc.cbSize        = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.style         = 0;
    wc.lpfnWndProc   = WndProc;
    // lots of other attrs ...
    wc.lpszClassName = g_szClassName;
    wc.hIconSm       = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);

    if(!RegisterClassEx(&wc))
        return 0;

    // Step 2: Creating the Window
    hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
        ...
        g_szClassName,
        ...);

    if(hwnd == NULL)
         return 0;

    ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hwnd);

    // Step 3: The Message Loop
    while(GetMessage(&Msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0)
    {
        TranslateMessage(&Msg);
        DispatchMessage(&Msg);
    }
    return Msg.wParam;
}
```

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: sure. added an example.

Comment: This looks good, and it's really more effective then the method I posted?

Comment: This is Windows way (pure async) of doing things. It also does not affect the app performance because there is no key polling within app.

Comment: Using MyWndProcHandler; in main just closes the application when I start.

Comment: You should define and register your window class (there you specify your WindowProc callback), create window based on registered window class and message loop. When the application receives a message, this loop dispatches it to the WndProc function to be handled. I'd suggest googling "Simple win32 application c++" to find out more

Comment: I've googled around a bit, but I still don't understand how I'm supposed to use that code :/

Comment: I've put complete win32 app skeleton to help you started.

Comment: Thank you. What can I do to call the function?

Comment: WndProc is called automatically by Win32 API when window message is received. I'd suggest you to read some book about Windows programming (Win32 API).

Comment: g_szClassName is undefined and I don't understand the point of the ellipsis. Sorry for the annoyance.

Comment: Its the name of your window class. const char g_szClassName[] = "myWindowClass"; I did use ... to simplify the code reading. Please use google to check the rest of function arguments.